# Show parent field in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, lwc-dom

I have a wizard on case object. The idea is to help agents to fill up the necessary data. however, I have trouble to show parent field (i.e Account.Name) in LWC HTML file.

Here is my code

**Controller**

```
public with sharing class CaseWizardController {
    @AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Case getCase(Id caseId){
        return [SELECT Id, CaseNumber, Origin, Unit__c, Country__c, RecordType.Name, ContactId, Contact.Name, AccountId, Account.Name FROM Case WHERE Id =:caseId LIMIT 1];
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import getCaseDetails from '@salesforce/apex/CaseWizardController.getCase';
import updateCase from '@salesforce/apex/CaseWizardController.updateCase';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class CaseWizard extends LightningElement {
    //pagination variables
    @track page = 1; //current page
    totalPages = 5; //total page

    @track error;

    @api recordId; //current caseId
    @api wiredCase;
    @api realCase;
    @track accountName;
    @track contactName;


    @wire(getCaseDetails, { caseId: '$recordId' })
    getCaseDetails(resp) {
        this.wiredCase = resp;
        this.realCase = { ... this.wiredCase.data };
        this.accountName = this.realCase.Account.Name; //tried this but it isn't working
        this.contactName = this.realCase.Contact.Name; //tried this but it isn't working
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <h2 slot="title">
            <lightning-icon icon-name="custom:custom9" size="small"></lightning-icon>
            &nbsp; Case Wizard
        </h2>
        <!--Case Information-->
        <template if:true={realCase}>
            <!--Requester-->
            <template if:true={firstPage}>
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <h1 class="slds-text-heading_small">Requester</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="account" readonly label="Account" value={accountName}>
                    </lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="contact" readonly label="Contact" value={contactName}>
                    </lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="client" readonly label="Client" value={realCase.Client_Type__c}>
                    </lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="clientSubType" readonly label="Client Sub Type"
                        value={realCase.Client_Sub_Type__c}>
                    </lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="relatedName" label="Related Name" value={realCase.Complainer_Name__c}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="relatedEmail" label="Related Email" value={realCase.Complainer_Email__c}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" name="relatedPhone" label="Related Phone" value={realCase.Go_Food_Complainer_Phone__c}></lightning-input>
                </div>
            </template>
       </template>
        <div slot="footer">
            <lightning-layout>
                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-button label="Previous" icon-name="utility:chevronleft" onclick={handlePrevious}
                        disabled={firstPage}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow"></lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-button label="Next" icon-name="utility:chevronright" icon-position="right"
                        onclick={handleNext} disabled={fifthPage}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item>
                    <lightning-button label="Submit" variant="brand" title="Submit action" icon-position="right"
                        onclick={handleSubmit} disabled={notFifthPage}></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>

        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Wire service] always return object with properties `data` and `error`. Initially, it returns with both `undefined` and so if you dont put conditions then you will get errors as you cant access `Name` of undefined. You can implement as below:

```
@wire(getCaseDetails, { caseId: '$recordId' })
consList({ data, error }) {
    if (data) {
        this.realCase = { ...data };
        this.accountName = this.realCase.Account.Name; //tried this but it isn't working
    } else if (error) {
        // handle error
        console.error('ERROR => ', error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @salesforce-sas, thanks man for pointing out, I missed that!